# Imported text from CSV wrapped in Excel cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Python 3.6 here. I am writing tweets into a csv with those three lines of code (I removed unnecessary code) :

```
self.csvTwitter = open("twitterDB.csv", 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
wr = csv.writer(self.csvTwitter, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(listeInfosTweet)
```

`listeInfoTweets` contains a list of string like below :

```
["966305843376476162","1519220240812","Wed Feb 21 13:37:20 +0000 2018","Bloomberg","New York and the World","4617407","Spotify's Daniel Ek is special, but not Mark Zuckerberg special","en"]
```

Then I need to access and process a bit this csv file  to write in excel. I use panda to load the data and xlwings to write it :

```
laData = pd.read_csv('twitterDB - 22042018.csv', encoding = "UTF-8")
```

The problem is that in excel, some cells are wrapped automatically like below, how i could avoid that and remove leading and trailing space and break line ? Thanks !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, after writing the text in the cell I write :

```
ws.range((i, 6)).api.WrapText = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tweets contain new line characters like `"\n"`

Try this to remove them:

```
# replaces all occurrences of '\n' with empty string ''
my_str= my_str.replace('\n','')
```

You will need to iterate over all the strings and apply this function.

If it is in a Pandas column, try the apply function

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Select as an answer if this helped!

Comment: I don't have "\n" in my initial csv as i write line with ````newline=''````. I just checked to be sure and there is any.